# Sort dictionary by value property

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

How can the dictionary

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.property = value
        
dictionary = {"one":Foo(1),
              "two":Foo(2)}
```

be sorted in descending order, by the value of the `Foo` object's `self.property`?

Comment: Do you wanna print them sorted? Because you can't sort a dictionary. You access them by `key` and not by index. Am I right?

Comment: [check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6). dictionaries in 3.6+ are insertion ordered

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```py
sorted_dict = {k: v for k, v in sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda item: item[1].property)}
```

Answer (score 3):

Easy - don't. A dictionary is a data structure which is designed to allow efficient association between the key and its value. As such, Python uses an ordering which facilitates that. If you need a sorted result, then select the values you need into a more appropriate structure (perhaps a list) and sort that.